# How to Get Current User Principal

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, userprincipal, groupprincipal

I want to use Windows Authentication and get User info such as Givenname, Surname, etc.
I used `UserPrincipal.Current` in IIS and I got an exception, but IIS express looks fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved by using a Find Method:

```
var domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var currentUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, User.Identity.Name);
```