# Get User DirectoryEntry after Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, active-directory

When a user is Windows authenticated in my WebAPI app, and I use `UserPrincipal.Current`, I get the error that

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal cannot be converted to System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal
>
> ```
> at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
> at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.get_Current()
> ```

I am [not the only one to have this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538184/how-to-get-current-user-principal).

But I have the `ApiController.User` object filled correctly. So I tried:

```
Principal principal = (Principal)User;
principal.GetUnderlyingObject(...
```

But it won't do, because

> IPrincipal cannot be converted to Principal

So, I have to convert to a Windows principal, which works:

```
WindowsPrincipal winPrincipal = (WindowsPrincipal)User;
```

And then I have to ask AD for that specific user:

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    Principal principal = Principal.FindByIdentity(pc, windowsPrincipal.Identity.Name);
    principal.GetUnderlyingObject(...
}
```

In 9 of 10 cases this works, but for some users, principal is null, although the user is authenticated. **The affected users are all part of a certain subdomain.** What am I overlooking? Is there another, more reliable, method to always get the AD principal of the Windows authenticated principal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the `IPrincipal` (and `IIdentity`) interfaces which are core .NET security interfaces separated from the `UserPrincipal` in AD - those are **NOT** the same thing and not related directly.

In AD, you can always use

```
UserPrincipal current = UserPrincipal.Current;
```

to get the current user's AD information

Comment: Using UserPrincipal.Current throws the error that "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal" cannot be converted to "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal" (`at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue), at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.get_Current()`). I just added that to the original post.

Comment: @Alexander: in that case, your web app might be running under an app pool that uses a Windows **group** - in that case, you need to cast it to `GroupPrincipal` instead

Comment: I don't need the app pool, I need the user that has logged in. And the "cast" that fails is done inside `UserPrincipal.get_Current()`, which is a Microsoft builtin - so I can't change that cast, I can only abstain from using `UserPrincipal.Current`.